# AngularJS and Less import

Tags: angularjs, less

I have an angular js project. I use Grunt to compile js and css ( for css I'm using less ). At this moment I create one file css with all style and theme. I have a folder with some style (theme-a.less, theme-b.less etc).

My question is: how can I change dynamic theme when user press button?? I think that I need to change import but I don't know how.

Thanks

FS

Answer (score 0):

:) try this configurations for grunt,
http://ericnish.io/blog/compile-less-files-with-grunt

Comment: This sounds good but I have compiled file before with grunt and I have one css with all style and ONE theme. So maybe I need to not compile theme-a.css and theme-b.css and use it separate?

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

Check this out!

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-angularjs-and-nghref-to-grab-css-dynamically

Basically, use ng-href and set the whole html to be the "theme" controller.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/{{ css }}/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: This sounds good but I have compiled file before with grunt and I have one css with all style and ONE theme. So maybe I need to not compile theme-a.css and theme-b.css and use it separate?

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

Font: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-angularjs-and-nghref-to-grab-css-dynamically

```js
angular.module('linkApp', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.css = 'cosmo';
   
  $scope.bootstraps = [
    { name: 'Basic', url: 'cosmo' },
    { name: 'Slate', url: 'slate' },
    { name: 'Sandstone', url: 'sandstone' }
  ];
  
  $scope.layout = 'normal';
  
  $scope.layouts = [
    { name: 'Boring', url: 'normal' },
    { name: 'Circles', url: 'circle' },
    { name: 'In Your Face', url: 'large' }
  ];

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- define our app and controller on html -->
<html ng-app="linkApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<head>

    <!-- pull in css based on angular -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/{{ css }}/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="layout-{{ layout }}.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- bring in JS and angular -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container">

    <!-- section to select styles -->
    <div class="well">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Theme</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="css" ng-options="bootstrap.url as bootstrap.name for bootstrap in bootstraps">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Layout</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="layout" ng-options="layout.url as layout.name for layout in layouts"></select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- our content -->
    <div class="picture-thing">
        <div class="picture-thing-img">
            <img src="http://scotch.io/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/picture-picture.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="picture-thing-content">
            <h2>Bananas</h2>
            <p>This demo is just that.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This sounds good but I have compiled file before with grunt and I have one css with all style and ONE theme. So maybe I need to not compile theme-a.css and theme-b.css and use it separate?